# How to mimic vb's control array in python for win32com?

Tags: python, win32com

I need to dynamically create com objects from an activex dll and each of the objects can raise events which should be handled with event handlers.

I can do this easily with `win32com.client.Dispatch` and `win32com.client.WithEvents` and associate a "separate" class of event handlers with each of the objects. Like so:

```
class evt_1:
    def OnEvent(self):
        print "got event from object 1"

class evt_2:
    def OnEvent(self):
        print "got event from object 2"

obj_1 = win32com.client.Dispatch("mycom")
ev_1  = win32com.client.WithEvents(obj_1, evt_1)

obj_2 = win32com.client.Dispatch("mycom")
ev_1  = win32com.client.WithEvents(obj_2, evt_2)
```

But if I dynamically create the objects, lets say in a list:

```
listOfObjects = []
for i in range(10):
    obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("mycom")
    listOfObjects.append(obj)
    ev = win32com.client.WithEvents(obj, MyEventHandlerClass)
```

I want to code the event handlers only once, since I don't know how many objects I would be creating until run time. And I don't know how to get the object that raised the event from inside the event handler.

In VB 6, I've used the activex control using **control arrays**, and the event handlers simply get an "index" value of the control that raised the event.

Do you think something similar can be done in python ?
I am not sure what python decorators work for, but can they be used to "decorate" the MyEventHandlerClass for each index of the com object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a major flaw of win32com's event handling that you have to pass in a class object rather than a class instance.

You can attach state to your classes using win32com, however, by creating classes dynamically using `new.classobj`:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch, WithEvents
from new import classobj

class MyEventHandler(object):
    def OnVisible(self, visible):
        print "got event from object %d" % self.obj_index

listOfObjects = []
for i in range(3):
    handler = classobj('Handler_%s' % i,(MyEventHandler,),{})
    handler.obj_index = i
    ie = Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")
    listOfObjects.append(ie)
    WithEvents(ie, handler)

listOfObjects[0].Visible = 1
listOfObjects[2].Visible = 1
```

Output:

```
got event from object 0
got event from object 2
```

You might want to look into the [comtypes](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/comtypes/) module (see [event handling](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/comtypes/#com-events)) if you want to do this in a saner way.

Comment: Yes! this works.. thanks Ryan
I will also look into the comtypes module.. looks a little different from win32com ..

Answer (score 0):

Control Arrays were removed in VB.NET so I don't think they would be supported in the win32com. 
Not sure if this would work for you but can you pass the index to the EventHandler class?

```
class MyEventHandler:
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.obj_index = index

    def OnEvent(self):
        print "got event from object %d" % self.obj_index

listOfObjects = []
for i in range(10):
    obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("mycom")
    listOfObjects.append(obj)
    ev = win32com.client.WithEvents(obj, MyEventHandlerClass(i))
```

If the event needs access to all of the controls in the array (not just the index), you can mimic a control array by looping through your listOfObjects in the EventHandler, and determining which object raised the Event... so for example, a RadioButton_CheckChanged() event would look like:

```
def RadioButton_CheckChanged():
    for radiobutton in listOfRadioButtons:
        if radiobutton.Checked:
            # this is the one that was clicked on
```

Comment: The great flaw of win32com for events is that you need to pass in a callable, and not an instance. However, you can pass in a wrapped "factory" function that will return a class instance with the necessary state.

Comment: @coonj: Unfortunately.. The WithEvents() function requires the name of a class instance, not an object reference so that didn't work. But I think your idea should work if we can pass in a new class having an index value in an `obj_index` variable. Is that possible? I remember reading somewhere that classes are objects in python too so I'm thinking they could be created but I'm not sure what the syntax would be..